# kubernetes controller or scheduler HA

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

In kubernetes, controller-manager and scheduler achieve HA by creating an Endpoint, for example:

[kube-scheduler Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj7Qu.png)

As far as i know, LeaderElection just create an endpoint without service. However, in endpoint controller, it will delete endpoints without corresponding services, which will cause leader transition.

[endpoints_controller source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/endpoint/endpoints_controller.go#L505)

I dont't know if i miss something important or the leader election exists bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You may understand the code wrong, here I assume you've already have knowledge about list-watch mechanism in APIServer.

In [NewEndpointController](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/endpoint/endpoints_controller.go#L68-L100), you can see that EndpointController only care about pod and service resource, only when these two kind of resource change(add/update/delete) will be caught by EndpointController. So create a standalone endpoint(this event) will not be captured by EndpointController, and will only remind kube-proxy create related network config in host.

Comment: I don't think so. checkLeftoverEndpoints funcs will run after controller start five minutes in a single gorouine. It is not event-inform mechainism, it just list all endpoints and process them.